# How to check if a player's score is 0 while standing on a emerald?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have a command that checks if a player's score is 0 and the block they’re standing on is emerald.
I wrote:

```
/execute as @a if block ~ ~-1 ~ emerald_block if score @s floor matches 0 run scoreboard players @s floor 1
```

but this looks at all players *simultaneously* for emerald and 0 score, rather than one at a time. I’m out of ideas to fix it.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Try adding `at @s` after `as @a` to run the command relative to each player.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `as @a` does not, by itself, change *where* the command is being executed, only *who* it is being executed by. So the `if block ~ ~-1 ~ emerald_block` is checking the block under the command block, not the block under the player.

Add `at @s` after the `as @a`. This will move command execution to the current entity's location before it checks the block.

Also, `scoreboard players @s floor 1` is not a valid command. You probably meant `scoreboard players set @s floor 1` (note the `set`).

The full fixed command would look something like

```
/execute as @a at @s if block ~ ~-1 ~ emerald_block if score @s floor matches 0 run scoreboard players set @s floor 1
```